# Entry point of the code when starting a play application

Tags: scala, playframework

This is my very first web application I program, so maybe this question is very obvious to some of you but I didn't find something on the [play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaHome) website. When looking at the starter application one part of the code looks like this:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(val controllerComponents: ControllerComponents) extends BaseController {
  def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
    Ok(views.html.index())
  }
}
```

So, now I am wondering, where does my `controllerComponents` come from? Where does my application start at? Usually, I can look for my `main` method or `extends App` but here I have really no clue where this one or in play, in general, I get my values from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer - the is no `main` method exposed in Play Framework app. It's hidden from developer, so framework do all application boot up stuff for you: dependency injection wirings, external resources creating (e.g. database connections in case of `slick` or other pluggable resources), port listening start etc. Such approach also known as [Hollywood principle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Hollywood_principle):

> Don't call us, we will call you

In case if you need to have control over application lifecycle, maybe the next do will be helpful for you: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/api/scala/play/api/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.html

Also if you like to have more precise control over application load process, probably you will need to create own `ApplicationLoader` as it said in this section: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/api/scala/play/api/inject/ApplicationLifecycle.html

Comment: What about play framework-2.0? I mean how could we handle its start, stop methods? As my onStart and onStop methods are not calling in Global class.

Comment: @Hafiz Hamza excuse me, please, for delayed reply. I'm sorry, but I did not work with 2.0 version, but I'm pretty sure, there should be similar mechanism.